# java desktop application for executing sql queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to create an java desktop application for executing sql queries (on a database) typed by an user in a textarea, (before I start coding) I want to know if there is any framework that can make things easier (because i want to do a text processing on the typed query)

The idea that I have in my mind is doing an query application like the one exist on phpmyadmin (like this one):
[image]

Comment: Your application is a nice idea but i think it is redundant in the sense that you already have this why design one. Even when you design yours you will still need a database server.

Comment: But if you still want to develop, then i guess go the hard way.

Comment: Thank you, for the database, I'll link the app to a mysql database

Comment: there is hibernate framework, you can use it

Comment: Use [mysql-java-connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). It's the basic driver for java. Create a connection and run the sql query. Not to use any framework if you want to learn.